# ¿En qué puede afectar mi cuenta tener reportes rechazados?

Tags: soporte, reportes

#### ¿En qué puede afectar mi cuenta tener reportes rechazados?

La pregunta obedece a la siguiente inquietud:

[image]

La imagen anterior fue reportada horas antes de la edición como "No adecuado para este sitio" y fue rechazado el reporte.

> Probablemente, el reporte más adecuado hubiese sido ***Necesita detalles y aclaraciones***, pero cuando lo reporté era una pregunta que no cumplía con el  formato del sitio en ese momento.

Sin embargo, la pregunta fue actualizada horas más tarde:

[image]

Tal y como se puede observar [en el siguiente enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/453771/revisions).

Esta inquietud obedece a que me rechazaron tres (03) reportes la vez anterior y no pude seguir generando nuevos reportes por un cierto tiempo.

Entonces, si reporto preguntas de baja calidad y que no cumplen con el formato del sitio y luego es actualizado, entonces, existe el riesgo de que el reporte sea rechazado, por lo tanto, la posibilidad de reportar puede verse afectada nuevamente.

Comment: Exacto, si reportas incorrectamente demasiadas veces, pueden quitarte ese privilegio.

Comment: @Excorpion no, eso no es cierto. Los privilegios se basan en la reputación; si reportas incorrectamente no pierdes reputación, por lo que no pierdes ese privilegio.

Comment: Como no ?? Y que dice abajo en la respuesta ?? `se te bloqueará la posibilidad de crear nuevos reportes.` ... `Lo único que pasa es que te quitan el privilegio por un tiempo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si algunos de tus reportes son rechazados, puede que veas un aviso advirtiéndote de que visites tu historial de reportes para revisarlos. Esto te da la oportunidad de poner esos consejos en práctica.

> De diez o más de tus reportes, si al menos una cuarta parte fue rechazado en los últimos 7 días, se te bloqueará la posibilidad de crear nuevos reportes. Este bloqueo dura hasta 7 días, después de los cuales podrás volver a reportar de nuevo. Nuestra intención es que tomes este tiempo para revisar tus reportes junto a las indicaciones de esta página y así vuelvas mejor informado. Recuerda, es gente como tú la que hace que todo esto funcione - ¡cuanto más preparados estemos para resolver problemas, mejor será Stack Overflow en español para todos!

Lo único que pasa es que te quitan el privilegio por un tiempo

<sub>Según [¿Qué son los reportes rechazados y qué debo hacer con ellos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags)</sub>

#### Pero, en lo que sea posible; por favor, evita

**Reportar publicaciones muy recientes**

Puede que reportar una publicación muy reciente sea eficaz (a veces), pero no siempre, pues los usuarios a veces editan su publicación y se convierte en formato válido para el sitio (tal como sucedió acá), es mejor esperar de uno a dos días (o incluso algunas cuantas horas) para poder reportar.

**Reportar publicaciones de usuarios nuevos**

Los usuarios nuevos no entienden cómo funciona el sitio todavía, así que es mejor dejarles un comentario para instruirlos y que mejoren su publicación, si un usuario simplemente no hace caso (en el tiempo dicho o más), puedes reportar la publicación recién.

---

Además, otra recomendación, es mejor esperar a que reporten la publicación como *de baja calidad* y acceder a las colas de revisión, pues desde ahí puedes *recomendar la eliminación* y usuarios con mayor reputación o moderadores se podrán encargar

**¡Ánimo!** Te falta muy poca reputación para llegar a los 3,000 puntos (suficientes para cerrar/reabrir preguntas), cuando llegues ¡Podrás encargarte tú mismo de preguntas mal formuladas!

Comment: Me gusta mucho esta respuesta.